# A-FRAME - The click of my cursor triggers the event of the portal even if it does not point on it

Tags: javascript, click, aframe, virtual-reality

I am doing an a-frame VR project where I need to make "portals" that are useful for the user to move from one room to another. My problem is that I use a cursor for the click event, but it trigger the portal event even if there is a huge gap between the cursor and the portal.

I am using a js.script that you can find here : https://github.com/stemkoski/A-Frame-Examples/blob/master/js/link-controls.js

There is my portal :

```
<a-link position="0 1.6 -14" rotation="0 0 0"
href="paris.html" title="Paris" image="#photoparis"></a-link>
```

As for my cursor, I just did a normal cursor inside the a-camera tag.

[See there, an example of the gap between cursor and portal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pMcx.png)

Can someone help me to understand why there is this problem ? I would like to specify that when I use only the cursor of my mouse there is not this problem and it is necessary that I click precisely on the portal so that the event is activated.

Thanks you in advance for your answers, and don't hesitate to tell me if there is something that I have poorly explained. Also, pardon me if I have made english mistake.

Comment: Share complete simple code illustrating your issue and it will be much easier to help you. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great for people to run it and suggest solutions. Best of luck!

Comment: Hello, I only use the VR cursor now and not the mouse anymore and I don't have any problem now. Anyway thanks for your link I'll go check it out to learn more. ;)